# How to get the hex decoded version of a Peer Id?

Tags: substrate-node-template, nodes, peers, subkey

I see this example on [Substrate's docs](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/permissioned-network/):

```
Node key: c12b6d18942f5ee8528c8e2baf4e147b5c5c18710926ea492d09cbd9f6c9f82a
PeerID (generated from the node key): 12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2
Decoded PeerID in hex: 0024080112201ce5f00ef6e89374afb625f1ae4c1546d31234e87e3c3f51a62b91dd6bfa57df
```

I can generate the node key and the PeerID with the `subkey` program e.g. `subkey generate-node-key`. However, I'm not sure how I can decode the PeerID in the Terminal. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

The PeerID is encoded in bs58.
So you need to decode it.

```
 node_authorization: NodeAuthorizationConfig {
   nodes: vec![
     (
       OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2").into_vec().unwrap()),
       endowed_accounts[0].clone()
     ),
     (
       OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWQYV9dGMFoRzNStwpXztXaBUjtPqi6aU76ZgUriHhKust").into_vec().unwrap()),
       endowed_accounts[1].clone()
     ),
   ],
 },
```

Here is an online BS58 decoder alive.

https://whisperd.tech/bs58-codec/